# Taking out the last letter of some items in a list

Tags: python, regex, list, data-cleaning

I have a list like the following:

```
['Singh Sumer',
 'Li Sheng\n',
 'Hahn Vanessa',
 'Ruiter Dana',
 'Kleinbauer Thomas',
 'Klakow Dietrich\n',
 'Caselli Tommaso']
```

Some members have '\n' at the end. I want to remove them and put them as following members of the list.

So, I want to have this as an output:

```
['Singh Sumer',
 'Li Sheng',
 '\n',
 'Hahn Vanessa'
 'Ruiter Dana',
 'Kleinbauer Thomas',
 'Klakow Dietrich',
 '\n',
 'Caselli Tommaso']
```

I tried to get the indexes of the members who have '/n' at the end and insert '/n' to those indexes. But when I used the insert function, it replaced them with the other members of the list . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

re.split with lookahead returns a list with the word and newline if present, or just the word

```
import re

lst = [
 'Singh Sumer',
 'Li Sheng\n',
 'Hahn Vanessa',
 'Ruiter Dana',
 'Kleinbauer Thomas',
 'Klakow Dietrich\n',
 'Caselli Tommaso'
]
r = []
for s in lst:
    r.extend(re.split(r'(?=\n)', s))
print(r)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is quite easy but you must keep in mind that "\n" is considered as single character, so you must consider that like only 1 letter.

That's how you can do that:

```
elements = ['Singh Sumer',
 'Li Sheng\n',
 'Hahn Vanessa',
 'Ruiter Dana',
 'Kleinbauer Thomas',
 'Klakow Dietrich\n',
 'Caselli Tommaso']

output = []

for index, element in enumerate(elements):
    output.append(element.strip())
    if element[-1:] == "\n":
        output.insert(index+1, "\n")

print (output)
```

The output is:

```
['Singh Sumer', 'Li Sheng', '\n', 'Hahn Vanessa', 'Ruiter Dana', 'Kleinbauer Thomas', '\n', 'Klakow Dietrich', 'Caselli Tommaso']
```